# Parsing html table

Tags: asp.net

I have a string for HTML table, which looks like

```
string = "<table><tr><td style="color:#FFF">12</td><td>16</td><td>65</td><td>45</td></tr>
          <tr><td width="20px;">2</td><td>56</td><td>34</td><td style="background      color:Red;">98</td></tr></table>";
```

I want to iterate through this table row by row, cell by cell and I DONT want to include the styling and stuff...

Can you show me a small example on how to do this in asp.net & c#.

Comment: Use HtmlAgilityPack -  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an HTML parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it will parse this fragment and let you query it using XPath or LINQ to XML syntax.